# How to set pgAdmin 4 to auto-drop table if required to alter it?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've come from MS SQL Server where there's an option in SSMS to allow the dropping of tables/views if required when altering them.

Is there the same option in pgAdmin for PostgreSQL?

When trying to change the type of an existing column in a table, I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR: cannot alter type of column used by a view or rule .... on view ... depends on column "name"
```

FWIW I'm changing the type from `text` to `character varying`, so it's hardly magician work

Comment: There are no benefits in using character varying over text in PostgreSQL. Under the hood these two data types are the same

Comment: Yes, views in Postgres behave pretty much like views in SQL Server that were created using `with schemabinding`. So you will have to drop the views first. This is easily done if you are using a proper schema management tool and store the migration scripts and view definitions in Git rather than messing around with a GUI. But as Frank already noted: switching from text to varchar changes nothing and is totally useless.

Comment: THanks for the info :) the reason I wanted to change it was for consistency. There are some columns set to text and some to character varying, so I wanted them all the same. Sounds like `text` is the way to go as it's shorter. I'm very new to Postgre!